# Java Servlet and Apache Tomcat 404 when redirecting to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've been struggling for days trying to figure out the solution to my problem.
I'm trying to develop a Web Application in Java with Tomcat.

This is my project stracture:

[image: Project Structure]

From what I've read I know that .jsp files should be placed in web directory, but when I do so I get a:

> HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

from the server which is not happening if all my .jsp files are placed directly inside "simpleLogin".

Furthermore this is my **index.jsp**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="LoginCheck"> <%--Action shows you where to go, we want to go from jsp to a servlet--%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                UserName:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="password"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="login"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **LoginCheck** servlet class:

```
package example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by AGDS on 5/23/2017.
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginCheck")
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

        //It will check weither username or password is correct

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        try {
            if (username.equals("java") && password.equals("1234")) {
                //Go to member's page
                response.sendRedirect("member.jsp");

            } else {
                //Go to error page
                response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

And this is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginCheck</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>example.LoginCheck</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginCheck</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginCheck</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now if I tried to hit the submit button that would result again to:

> HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

I suppose that something's wrong with my paths and the location that my .jsp files are located or something's wrong with my mapping in the web.xml .

Any suggestion/proposal would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the servlet being called?

Comment: I suppose yes because the url changes from `localhost:8085/` where the form is displayed to `localhost:8085/LoginCheck` where a  `404` is showed up!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to put html/jsp content into a directory named web. It is something that your IDE does for you for convenience. For example eclipse will create a directory called WebContent for the same purpose.

So if you want to manage your project with Intelij be sure that InteliJ is configured correctly to handle it as Java web application.

See this for detailes:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-web-application.html

Comment: I have totally created a new Web Application and configured Tomcat for in IntelliJ. Tomcat manages to Deploy the server and successfully return the index.jsp but doesn't do so with my servlet call, isn't it weird?

Comment: Instead of response.sendRedirect could you please try something like that:
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("member.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: I still get a `404`

Comment: Interesting. I have no InteliJ Ultimate to try it, but you may find some clue if you look into the war file that generated by InteliJ. Or check your Tomcat's webbapps direcory and see how does your application look like when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

404 error means that file is not existing or you didn't provide the filepath correctly
Once you hit the the submit button the URL should be like `localhost:8085/simpleLogin/LoginCheck`not`localhost:/LoginCheck`